# Text input in C++

Tags: c++, text

I have a quick question about text input in C++. I have a code where i can have a person type in a number but I have tried changing the number to text and it wont work. I am making a text-based game and I want people to be able to type words instead of just numbers. Here is some example code:

```
    int Choice;
    if(Choice == 1)
    {
    printf ("You press the restart button on the system but nothing seems to happen\n");
}
```

I want the person to be able to type in "Press Button instead of typing "1"

Also I have another question, Is there a way to be able to have the console check if the person typed in something right and if they didn't it would let them retype their answer?

Thanks for reading and please answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is easiest with `std::string`: (`#include <string>`)

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
if(input == "Press Button") { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try either

```
std::string str = std::cin.getline();
```

or

```
char[50] str;
std::cin << str
```

Comment: Is your 2nd example safe?

Comment: Let's say the user types more than 50 characters...

Comment: I think that only 50 chars get used, the rest are disposed of properly, i.e. no memory leaks. Also, OP can change the '50' to whatever he deems safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
std::string s;
std::cout << "Type something: ";
std::cin >> s;

while ( s != "Correct string" ) 
{
    std::cout << "Type again: ";
    std::cin >> s;
}
```